# PHP/CakePHP : Relation HasOneBelongToOne

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm trying to figured out what's the best way to make a "Has One Belong to One" relation  in CakePHP. Unfortunatly I didn't found anything for helping me on the internet.

I've tried to proceed like that:

Company model :

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

User model :

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className'    => 'Company',
        //'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent'    => true
    )
);
```

But still cakePHP allow me to create two companies for one user.

And here my database schema :
Company : id, name, ..., user_id
User : id, name, ...

Many thanks

Comment: here is everything ok, you problem isn't here, i think somewhere in code

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP can handle the following relationships only:

- one to one
- one to many
- many to one
- many to many

[Read more here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1040/Relationship-Types)

If you want to do "Has One Belong to One" then use the `hasOne` feature in both objects.

Answer (score 0):

If each user has only one company and each company belongs to one and only one user, shouldn't they be on the same table?

like:

```
USER
Id
Name
...
Company
```

Sorry if I shouldn't ask questions back here but seemed pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

In your database, company table, user_id should be set unique.